# How can you hack an existing drupal module and add an entity reference?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am using imagefield marker and would like the description boxes to load nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use preprocess. That is for the theming layer.

Use [the Field API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7).

If it's for a particular field on a node edit form, use [a form alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to change the array of the form element.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna modify field behaviour you can use the preprocess field hook in your template.php

```
template_preprocess_field(&$vars, $hook){
if($vars['element']['#field_name'] == 'myfield')
$variables['loaded_node'] = drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)));
}
```

And then create the theme file **field--field-name.tpl.php** and print the variable from there.

Hope that helps your question is kinda vague on what you want to do.

Comment: This would work in the node edit area? I have an image field, the module allows you to add markers to the image. When you click on the image you can input text and the view then has a marker and rollover with the text. Instead of text I want a node to go there. Your template override will work for this?

Comment: No, you are gonna need to hack the module. Or check if it has any exposed hooks or something that will help you run php code in there. You could also add some custom string in there (with the node id) and use ajax to load the content in there or check in the preprocess field if you can load it from there. Good luck.